# Magento EE 1.14.3.2 Solr Version

Tags: magento-enterprise, search, enterprise-1.14, solr

Which version of Solr does Magento EE 1.14.3.2 support out of the box? Is it still 3.6.2?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html#ee114-11432), Magento EE 1.14 onwards supports Solr versions up to 3.6.2 natively (that is, without a patch).